# Help configuring JNDI with embedded JBoss in Tomcat 5.5.x

Tags: java, jboss, seam, jndi, embedded-jboss

When I try the following lookup in my code:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
return (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: QueryResults: Unable to initialize naming context: 
    Name java:comp is not bound in this Context at 
    com.onsitemanager.database.ThreadLocalConnection.getConnection
    (ThreadLocalConnection.java:130) at     
    ...
```

I installed embedded JBoss following the JBoss [wiki instructions](http://wiki.jboss.org/wiki/Tomcat5.5.x?action=e&windowstate=normal&mode=view).  And I configured Tomcat using the "Scanning every WAR by default" deployment as specified in the [configuration wiki page](http://wiki.jboss.org/wiki/EmbeddedAndTomcat).

Quoting the config page:

> JNDI
>
> Embedded JBoss components like connection pooling, EJB, JPA, and transactions make 
>   extensive use of JNDI to publish services. Embedded JBoss overrides Tomcat's JNDI 
>   implementation by layering itself on top of Tomcat's JNDI instantiation. There are a few > reasons for this:
>
> 1. To avoid having to declare each and every one of these services within server.xml
> 2. To allow seemeless integration of the java:comp namespace between web apps and 
>      EJBs.
> 3. Tomcat's JNDI implementation has a few critical bugs in it that hamper some JBoss 
>      components ability to work
> 4. We want to provide the option for you of remoting EJBs and other services that can > be remotely looked up

Anyone have any thoughts on how I can configure the JBoss naming service which according to the above quote is overriding Tomcat's JNDI implementation so that I can do a lookup on java:comp/env?

FYI - My environment Tomcat 5.5.9, Seam 2.0.2sp, Embedded JBoss (Beta 3),

Note:  I do have a -ds.xml file for my database connection properly setup and accessible on the class path per the instructions.

Also note: I have posted this question in embedded Jboss forum and seam user forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the response toolkit.... yes, I can access my datasource by going directly to java:jdbc/mydb, but I'm using an existing code base that connects via the ENC.  Here's some interesting info that I've found out ....

1. The above code works with **JBoss 4.2.2.GA** and here's the JNDI ctx parameters being used:
   java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces:
   org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
2. The above code works with **Tomcat 5.5.x** and here's the JNDI ctx parameters being used:
   java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory
   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.apache.naming
3. The above code fails with **Embedded JBoss (Beta 3)** in Tomcat 5.5.x with the above error message. 
   java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory
   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.apache.namingThe above code fails with the above error using JBoss Embedded in tomcat 5.5.x

Anyone have any thoughts I what I need to do with configuring embedded JBoss JNDI configuration?

Comment: Did you find a solution? 
I am also having this problem. Application works fine with native tomcat, datasources work as expected, but when JBoss is embedded I get a "Name java:comp is not bound in this Context" error.

Answer (score 1):

java:comp/env is known as the Enterprise Naming Context (ENC) and is not globally visible. See [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=384904) for more information. You will need to locate the global JNDI name which your datasource is regsitered at.

The easiest way to do this is to navigate to JBoss' web-based JMX console and look for a 'JNDIView' (not exactly sure of the name - currently at home) mbean. This mbean should have a list method which you can invoke, which will display the context path for all of the JNDI-bound objects.

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar issue with Jboss Embedded and i finally fix playing in the file:
test-Datasource-ds.xml

adding

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.naming.NamingAlias" name="jboss.jmx:alias=testDatasource">
    <attribute name="FromName">jdbc/Example DataSource</attribute>
    <attribute name="ToName">java:/testDatasource</attribute>
</mbean>
```

The problem was jboss add the prefix java:/ for all data source declared. So finally i had a datasource named testDatasource, overrided with that directive to jdbc/Example DataSource

Hope it works